# UIBarbutton action not working with UIDatePicker

Tags: ios, iphone

I am working on the Date picker and doing well, but theaction on the DONE button in the toolbar of the datepicker is not working.
Please helpme out in solving this issue.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
 - (IBAction)timepicker:(id)sender {
     timepicker.hidden = NO;

     NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
     df.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterShortStyle;
     timebtn.titleLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[df stringFromDate:timepicker.date]];
     UIToolbar *toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
     toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
     toolbar.frame=CGRectMake(0,4,timepicker.frame.size.width,40);

     UIBarButtonItem *flexibleSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];

     UIBarButtonItem *doneBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(pickerDoneClicked:)];

     [toolbar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:doneBtn] animated:NO];

     [timepicker addSubview:toolbar];

 }

 - (IBAction)pickerDoneClicked:(id)sender
 {
     NSLog(@"DONE IS PRESSED");
     [timepicker setHidden:YES];
 }
```

Comment: Can you please me more specific than "not working"?

Comment: the code checks out fine. try putting a breakpoint on both the methods and debug. post some more code snippets. maybe the problem lies elsewhere

Comment: @staticVoidMan i did this also bt not able to locate the error....

Answer (score 0):

Use this method instead of - (IBAction)pickerDoneClicked:(id)sender

```
- (void)pickerDoneClicked:(id)sender
 {
     NSLog(@"DONE IS PRESSED");
     [timepicker setHidden:YES];
 }
```

Comment: @sahil, pls drop comment if my answer helps to u

Answer (score 0):

`IBAction` is short for Interface Builder Action, it is invoked on a control event defined in interface builder (xibs and storyboards editor). Although `IBAction` resolves to void your controller won't recognise it if you have defined the target and action in code.

So, use `void` return type, as Ramdy said.

```
- (void)pickerDoneClicked:(id)sender
 {
     NSLog(@"DONE IS PRESSED");
     [timepicker setHidden:YES];
 }
```

Comment: You aren't getting the NSLog?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding both the `UIToolbar` and the `UIDatePicker` (with appropriate frame sizes) to a `UIView` before adding it to the subview.

I experienced the same issue and it turned out that the picker view was overlapping the toolbar causing the `UIDatePicker` to hijack the selector wired to the `UIBarButtonItem`.

```
// picker with the appropriate x,y,w,h (216 is default height of UIDatePicker)
timepicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 44, self.view.bounds.size.width, 216)];
timepicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeTime;
[timepicker addTarget:self action:@selector(timePickerValueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

UIBarButtonItem *timePickerDoneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(timePickerDoneTapped:)];
UIBarButtonItem *timePickerFlex = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];
// toolbar with appropriate x,y,w,h
UIToolbar *timePickerToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 44)];
[timePickerToolbar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleDefault];
[timePickerToolbar sizeToFit];
[timePickerToolbar setItems:@[timePickerFlex,timePickerDoneButton] animated:YES];

// view with appropriate x,y,w,h
UIView *timePickerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 260)];
[timePickerView addSubview:timePickerToolbar];
[timePickerView addSubview:timepicker];
```